# Compile in Fedora and run on Android

Tags: android, linux, gcc, adb, fedora

Is it possible to compile a c code in Fedora and to run it on Android with gcc? I tried to compile using `gcc file.c -o f1` and it didn't work. Any seggustions? I was unable to execute it with ADB tool.

Comment: I don't know the first thing about using C in android, but a quick google search came up with this: http://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-compiling-deploying-native-projects-android-ndk

Comment: That will not work for many reasons.  Android uses ARM CPU, Fedora runs on Intel.  Fedora uses ELF binary, Android uses APK.  Android primarily uses Java (although the Native NDK can use C - but it still must be placed into the APK somehow).  Goto http://http://developer.android.com/ and download the SDK and NDK to get started.

Answer (score 0):

If your c code is run in terminal, you can simple cross compile it and push the executable file to your phone by using ADB tools.

1. get a cross compiler

   - download a cross compiler, for example:
     [http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-            codebench/editions/lite-edition/](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/)
   - you can build android develop environment from:
     http://source.android.com/source/building.html
2. use arm-eabi-gcc for compiling your c code , generate executable file ie. a.out
3. adb push a.out /sdcard, chmod 777, then you can run it from adb shell